# Input Impedance calculation

Tags: filter, impedance

I am trying to calculate input impedence of a MFB low pass filter. What I need is the symbolic expression as simple as possible so that later I fill in the values and get the impedence itself:

[image]

I am not sure if I am on the right track...specially about the current directions I choosed. would somone kindly verify the steps?

What I need obviously is a simple equation with no current in it!

[image]

Comment: I always hated these stuff ....:)

Comment: what's the reason of "-i3" ?

Comment: Actually for no particular reason, I just felt lucky to put i3 like tha, it can be +i3 as well...does it matter?

Comment: how come there is 2 i3 ?

Comment: i3 and -i3 are sum of the current in that node which should be 0

Comment: Also that no current can go into amplifier

Comment: I cant see anything wrong in your equations

Comment: See my answer at http://math.stackexchange.com/a/108866/18398

Comment: Closed as off-topic??? This is clearly electronics. Voted to reopen!

Comment: Why is this closed? I don't know how to vote to reopen.